# How to get unique values in a string in my sql

Tags: mysql, group-concat, distinct-values

For example:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(seatnum) 
  from busses 
 where bus_id=19229;
```

This is resulting as `7,1,2,3,1,7,4`. I have to get only `7,1,2,3,4`, i.e unique values in mysql query. `Distinct` will not solve my problem here.

So pls let me know is their any other ideas in this?
Thanks.

Comment: Try DISTINCT again. 'Busses' is a rather archaic spelling.

Comment: do you not need a `group by`?